# What is difference between adding a character and pushing a character in a string?

Tags: c++

I was doing a question where I was adding a character using for loop in string like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    str = ch + str;
}
```

This code was running fine for small inputs. But when the input became quite large the memory limit exceeded.
Then I switched my code with:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    str.push_back(ch);
}
reverse(str.begin(),str.end());
```

And it worked. I want to know the reason why for my own understanding.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin See [overload 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B)

Comment: *"And it worked"* - highly situationally. Consider a string `"123"` and value `'a'`. In the first case the result is `"a123"` . In the second case the result is `"a321"`. So, if by "worked" you mean "didn't crash and gave me different results", ok then. But the only initial string that produces the *same* results from both cases is an *empty* string.

Comment: @WhozCraig I started with an empty string and i was pushing one character at a time using for loop. So in the second case my string would have been "321" before pushing "a".

Comment: Ahh. that makes sense. so you're building the string backwards *entirely* with N pushes, then reversing it once. That would be a considerably different use-algorithm than what we were first presented, for sure. Anyway, Alan's explanation is sound. The first, especially in that loop, will be generating and destroying a lot of strings via copies. The second does no such thing, only expanding as-needed; everything is done in-place, including the final reversal. FYI, since you "know" the length of the string beforehand, `n`, in the second case, a `str.reserve(n)` beforehand would be ideal.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that overload has been present since before c++11, no new overloads have been added after c++11

Comment: @AlanBirtles - I have a bit flipped somewhere. (not uncommon). Thanks for clearing that up. I was stuck on literal concatenation, but that clearly doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 1):

The first adds a character to the beginning of the string. I'm order to do this it creates a new string containing just `ch`, then it copies all of `str` in to it then moves this temporary string back into `str`. This operation requires at least enough memory to hold two copies of the string.

The second adds a character on to the end of the existing string, the string likely already has space for this character so just appends the character without using any additional memory. At some point the string will need to grow, at this point you'll again need more memory, typically this would need enough memory for the current size of the string plus the new size (e.g if the string implementation decides to double in size you'll need enough memory for three times the current size of the string)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes much more sense now

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is due to memory fragmentation and being very close to the out-of-memory boundary.

In `str = ch + str;` you are allocating a new string that is 1 char longer every time and then freeing the old string. If there are no other allocations it will need about 3 times the total length of the string of memory. If there are any other allocations in the loop then it can go as high as `O(n^2)`.

With `str.push_back(ch);` the string will grow by some factor when it reaches capacity causing a lot fewer allocations. Without other allocations this could still be something like 2.3 times the total string size. With allocations it could be `O(n * log(n))` where log is to the base of the growth factor.